# scp between 2 AWS Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, scp, instances

I have 2 **AWS** instances of Ubuntu 14.04.

One instance is the **master ELK server**. 
The other instance will be the **log forwarder** for logstash.

As part of the online instructions to setup the forwarder I enter the following on the ELK server instance:

```
scp /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt user@client_server_private_address:/tmp
```

I replace user with ubuntu and the private address with the public DNS name for the Log Forwarder instance.

Both are in the same VPC and Security Group. 
When I run

```
scp -v
```

I get:

```
No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Look up multi-hopping

Comment: why use public DNS name? are both instances in same VPC?

Comment: Same VPC.. Here is scp -v

Comment: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection

Comment: Did you generate an SSH key on that machine, and have you copied its public key to the remote machine's `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

Comment: Nope. Newbie error. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur when the destination host don't have inbound traffic allowance for the source machine from which the file has been sent.

Open the TCP port on the destination inbound rule for the source machine as follow:

```
Step1: Go to the security group associated with the destination machine.

Step2: Open TCP port in the inbound rule for the source machine.
```

Now try

```
scp /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt user@client_server_private_address:/tmp
```

command from the source machine

Hope it helps.....